# Color parameter in a Pine Script function doesn't respond to if condition

Tags: function, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am running into very odd results when I try and make Pine Script functions and I am not sure why. Here I have a function that will help me update lines that I keep in Arrays. The issue that I run into is with the _color variable. When I call the function with a color, everything is fine, but if I don't enter a color it will make the line disappear on the next bar, instead of leaving the default color that I had set previously. Please help me understand why this is happening.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Latest Swing and Direction Finder", "Swing Direction", true)

// VARIABLES                
//+-----------------------------------------------------+
//{

type lineShape
    line ln
    int arrIndex

//}

// FUNCTIONS 
//+-----------------------------------------------------+
//{
f_nearestSwing(int barsBack) =>
    float extremePrice = high
    int extremeTime = time[1]
    int indx = 1
    while indx <= barsBack
        if high[indx] > extremePrice
            extremePrice := high[indx]
            extremeTime := time[indx]
        indx += 1
    [extremeTime, extremePrice]


method newLine(array<lineShape> _lineArr, lineShape _lineObj, int x1, float y1, int x2, float y2, string extend=extend.none, color _color=color.white, string style=line.style_solid, int width=1) =>
    _lineObj.ln         := line.new(x1, y1, x2, y2, xloc.bar_time, extend, _color, style, width)
    _lineObj.arrIndex   := na(array.size(_lineArr)) ? 0 : array.size(_lineArr)
    array.push(_lineArr, _lineObj)
    _lineObj


// this function accepts the shape array that always only has one entry. 
method updateLine(array<lineShape> _lineArr, int _lineArrID, int _x1=na, float _y1=na, int _x2=na, float _y2=na, color _color=na) =>
    for [x, item] in _lineArr
        if x == _lineArrID
            target = item.ln
            if _x1
                line.set_x1(target, _x1)
            if _y1
                line.set_y1(target, _y1)
            if _x2
                line.set_x2(target, _x2)
            if _y2
                line.set_y2(target, _y2)
            if not na(_color)
                line.set_color(target, _color) 
        item
//}

// EXECUTION
//+-----------------------------------------------------+

var bool init = false
var lineArray = array.new<lineShape>()
var highLine = lineShape.new()
if barstate.islast
    [highBarTime, swingHighPrice] = f_nearestSwing(20)
    if not init
        lineArray.newLine(highLine, highBarTime, swingHighPrice, time, swingHighPrice, _color = color.purple)
        init := true
    else 
        // This code will not work 
        //lineArray.updateLine(highLine.arrIndex, highBarTime, swingHighPrice, time, swingHighPrice)
        // This code works
        lineArray.updateLine(highLine.arrIndex, highBarTime, swingHighPrice, time, swingHighPrice, color.purple)
```

I tested each if statement until I figured out that it was the _color variable giving me issues. I checked to make sure that I can initialize the color parameter to na and that is how it's supposed to be done. When you first load the code you will see the purple line appear at the nearest high, but if you use bar replay to advance time, the line simply disappears. I have included both the working and non-working code above with comments.

I think there is something fundamentally wrong with my understanding of how functions work. Any clarity reading would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In pinescrip if your draw something with color=na, pinescript won't draw anything.
Your method gives na value by default to 'color'.
So if you call your method without any color, your method will apply na to color and pinescript won't draw the line.

Try with this declaration to see the difference :

```
method updateLine(array<lineShape> _lineArr, int _lineArrID, int _x1=na, float _y1=na, int _x2=na, float _y2=na, color _color=color.blue) =>
```

In this case,

```
lineArray.updateLine(highLine.arrIndex, highBarTime, swingHighPrice, time, swingHighPrice)
```

will draw a blue line, as the default color defined in your method.

Comment: I didn't actually set the color to anything. I wrote an if statement to make sure that I only set the color if I actually receive one. If I don't receive a color, then it should continue using the color it had before.

Comment: @Xalladus I understand, but if you call your method without sending color, your method will apply na to the color, you define it this way. Did you try to modify your method as I propose you in my answer ? Just to see the difference ?

Comment: Yes, your solution would have me hard code in a set color. The purpose of this method is to allow users to update only the parts that need updating. For example: 
lineArray.updateLine(highLine.arrIndex, _x2 = time, _y2 = swingHighPrice, _color = color.purple) 
This will leave the x1 and x2 locations, and update everything else. This is controlled by the if statements, but the if statement for _color is seemingly ignored. That is the original issue.